# Formatting reset after list

Tags: html, css, list

I'm having some trouble formatting some text that appears after an ordered list.  The text after the list is no longer indented.  Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Practice Site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prac_style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Practice Website</h1>
    <div id="content">
    <div class="post">
    <p>
    List of things:
    <ol>
        <li>Item 1
        <li>Item 2
        <li>Item 3
    </ol>
    Text after list.
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #FFEEEB;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: justify;
}

#content {
  float: left;
  width: 700px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#content .post {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
}

#content .post p {
  margin: 10px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason is that your HTML is not properly formatted. You shouldn't wrap an `<ol>` list inside a `<p>` tag. Also, I recommend you close the open `<li>` tags too.

Try this HTML instead:

```
<body>
    <h1>Practice Website</h1>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="post">
            <p>List of things:</p>
            <ol>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ol>
            <p>Text after list.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think you _have_ to close `<li>` tags in HTML5 as "it's implied that a new tag would not be able to be started without closing it".

Comment: @davidpauljunior you're correct, the `<li>` tags in this case don't have to be closed; but it's just cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: I agree, just thought I'd mention.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked perfectly.  And I'll go ahead and add the missing closing tags.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the browser is automatically ending the `<p>` tag before the `<ol>`. It's kind of like how you don't end your `<li>` tags because you know they will be ended automatically.(Which, by the way, is not the proper way of doing it.)

To fix this, just put the 'List of things:' and 'Text after list.' in their own separate `<p>` tags like this:

```
<p>List of things:</p>
<ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
<p>Text after list.</p>
```

If you have Chrome our some other browser with 'inspect element', use that and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Lists get given padding by default, other elements don't.  You either need to apply the same padding to the `<p>` tag so they line up, or reset the padding and the list-style-position of the `<ol>`.

Also, don't nest `<ol>` inside `<p>`, it's not allowed.  And close your `<li>` tags (`</li>`).  Although I don't think it's required in HTML5, it is best practice.

Try:

```
<h1>Practice Website</h1>
<div id="content">
  <div class="post">
    <p>List of things:</p>
    <ol>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ol>
    <p>Text after list.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

To reset the list indentation use:

```
ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
}
```

You can then control the padding on the parent `<div>` if you want the whole block indented.

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/muqikubu/3/edit)**

Comment: Thanks!  The advice on how to control the padding really helped.